# D’oraita Sources for Halacha

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, posek-psak-decisor-ruling

We often see that the author of a p'sak maintains that a ruling is d’oraita even in cases when there is no link to any of the 613 mitzvot listed by Rambam, etc. Must every halacha ruled as a d’oraita be able to be traced back to one of the 613 mitzvot?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Could you please [edit] into your post some examples of such pesakim? That would make this a much stronger question. Please [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/5551) to give yourself a name, unless 5551 has some special significance to you!

Comment: See here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28054/what-is-so-special-about-the-613-mitzvos/33444#33444